# Knex pool was destroyed - getaddrinfo ENOENT

Tags: knex.js

I've been running mocha tests where a db is populated with knex. I was changing one of tests and ran into this error:

```
Knex:warning - Pool2 - Error: Pool was destroyed
Knex:Error Pool2 - Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT localhost:5432

Error: Pool was destroyed
at Pool._destroyPool (...\node_modules\pool2\lib\pool.js:548:20)
at Pool.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\pool2\lib\pool.js:465:18)
at Pool.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\pool2\lib\pool.js:505:17)
at tryCatcher (...\node_modules\knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
at Promise.errorAdapter (...\node_modules\knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\nodeify.js:36:34)
at Promise._settlePromiseAt (...\node_modules\knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:579:21)
at Promise._settlePromises (...\node_modules\knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:697:14)
at Async._drainQueue (...\node_modules\knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:123:16)
at Async._drainQueues (...\node_modules\knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:133:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (...\node_modules\knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:15:14)
```

I changed the tests back to how they were when they were still working, but I can't get rid of the error, I've tried restarting the computer and recreating the db but I'm out of ideas. Anyone else know how to fix this?